# Centroid of region btw $y=3\sin(x)$ and $y=3\cos(x)$ on $[0,\pi/4]$

Tags: calculus

I am working on some calc2 online problems and I seem to be stuck on one of the problems. The question reads: "Find the centroid of the region lying between the graphs of the functions $y=3\sin(x)$ and $y=3\cos(x)$ over the interval $[0,\pi/4]$." I am really lost on how to approach this problem so if someone could explain it step by step that would be greatly appreciated. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

Let $(x,y)$ be the center of mass. Then, let
$$A=\int^{\pi/4}_0(3\cos(x)-3\sin(x))dx$$
Then,
$$x=\dfrac{1}{A}\int^{\pi/4}_0x(3\cos(x)-3\sin(x))dx\\
y=\dfrac{1}{A}\int^{\pi/4}_0\dfrac{1}{2}(9\cos^2(x)-9\sin^2(x))dx$$
So, the center of mass is located at
$$\left(\dfrac{\int^{\pi/4}_0x(3\cos(x)-3\sin(x))dx}{\int^{\pi/4}_0(3\cos(x)-3\sin(x))dx},\dfrac{\int^{\pi/4}_0\dfrac{1}{2}(9\cos^2(x)-9\sin^2(x))dx}{\int^{\pi/4}_0(3\cos(x)-3\sin(x))dx}\right)$$
This is easy to evaluate if you expand the integrals.

**EDIT:** Let's evaluate the integrals:
$$A=\int^{\pi/4}_0(3\cos(x)-3\sin(x))dx=3\left(\int^{\pi/4}_0(\cos(x))dx-\int^{\pi/4}_0(\sin(x))dx\right)=3\left(\sin(x)+\cos(x)\right)|^{\pi/4}_0=3\left(\frac{2}{\sqrt{2}}\right)-3\left(1\right)=\frac{6}{\sqrt{2}}-3$$
Then,
$$\int^{\pi/4}_0(3x\cos(x)-3x\sin(x))dx=\int^{\pi/4}_0(3x\cos(x))dx+\int^{\pi/4}_0(3x\sin(x))dx$$
You can show that this is
$$3(x\sin(x)+\cos(x))|^{\pi/4}_0+3(\sin(x)-x\cos(x))|^{\pi/4}_0=3\left(\frac{\pi}{4\sqrt{2}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\right)-3+3\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}-\frac{\pi}{4\sqrt{2}}\right)=3(\sqrt{2}+1)$$
So,
$$\int^{\pi/4}_0(3x\cos(x)-3x\sin(x))dx=3(\sqrt{2}+1)$$
The second integral is
$$\int^{\pi/4}_0\dfrac{1}{2}(9\cos^2(x)-9\sin^2(x))dx$$
This you can show is
$$\int\dfrac{1}{2}(9\cos^2(x)-9\sin^2(x))dx=\dfrac{9}{4}\left((x+\sin(x)\cos(x))+(\sin(x)\cos(x)-x)\right)=\dfrac{9}{4}\left(2\sin(x)\cos(x))\right)=\dfrac{9}{4}\sin(2x)$$
Evaluated from ${\pi/4}$ to $0$ gives
$$\int^{\pi/4}_0\dfrac{1}{2}(9\cos^2(x)-9\sin^2(x))dx=\dfrac{9}{4}\sin(2x)|^{\pi/4}_0=\dfrac{9}{4}$$
So, you have the center of mass at
$$\left(\dfrac{\int^{\pi/4}_0x(3\cos(x)-3\sin(x))dx}{\int^{\pi/4}_0(3\cos(x)-3\sin(x))dx},\dfrac{\int^{\pi/4}_0\dfrac{1}{2}(9\cos^2(x)-9\sin^2(x))dx}{\int^{\pi/4}_0(3\cos(x)-3\sin(x))dx}\right)=
\left(\dfrac{3(\sqrt{2}+1)}{\dfrac{6}{\sqrt{2}}-3},\dfrac{9}{\dfrac{24}{\sqrt{2}}-12}\right)\approx\left(5.828427\ldots,1.810666\ldots\right)$$

Comment: Thank you so much for helping me! I understand how you set up the problem, my issue is that I don't know how to solve the integrals. If you have time, do you think you can help walk me through a step by step explanation of solving the integrals?

Comment: @user124539 See my edit in the answer.